# CSS3: Creating a vertical nav that is rotated 270deg

Tags: html, css, transform, nav

I am trying to create a vertical nav bar that is rotated 270deg (so that the links go upwards instead of across). The trouble I am having is that I need a fixed width (of 200px) and an equal height of 522px per link. When I apply the height it doesn't go down on one line and positioned strangely.

Any help would be great.

This is what I would like to try and do:

[image]

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q8j1y0w8/1/

```
<div class="main">
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav1"><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav2"><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav3"><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
    <li class="btn"><a href="#">Btn</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="content">CONTENT</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will bring the code close to the design image. It involves updating the CSS and reordering the HTML to generate the desired result.

Updated Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q8j1y0w8/9/

#### CSS

When the elements are rotated using CSS transforms, the rendered width becomes the visible height.

For the `ul.nav` element, the `width` is set at `1666px`, equivalent to the sum of the menu items' individual heights: `522px + 522px + 522px + 100px`. This will give the nav enough visible height to contain all the elements without overflowing.

```
.nav {
    width: 1666px; /* 522 + 522 + 522 + 100 = 1666 */
}
```

Each menu item is then given the appropriate heights by setting their CSS widths:

```
li {
    width: 100px;
}
li.nav1, li.nav2, li.nav3 {
    width: 522px;
}
```

#### HTML

The menu items are reordered like this, as the rotation means items from left to right are orientated to be from top to bottom.

```
<li class="btn"><a href="#">Btn</a></li>
<li class="nav3"><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
<li class="nav2"><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
<li class="nav1"><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
```

#### Notes

In the jsfiddle, I've set `ul.nav` to have an absolute position and `body` to have no margins to allow scrolling of the page so the entire navbar can be inspected.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Appreciate the feedback. That's seems to have done the job.